# Show a series of functions has a continuous sum.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ define
$$I(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if} & x \leq 0,\\ 1 & \text{if} & x > 0 \end{cases}$$
Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence of points in $(a, b)$ and that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty c_n$ converges absolutely. Prove that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty c_n I(x - x_n)$ converges uniformly for $x \in [a, b]$, and that $f$ is continuous for all $x \neq x_n$.

I have shown that the series converges absolutely by the comparison test. I was unsure of where to start for the continuity.

I was wondering if I could get a hint.

Thanks!

Comment: @Yimin Sure, this is the part the OP knows how to do.

Comment: oops, I see it now. For continuity, you just have to figure out the tail is always small, for $x,\tilde{x}\neq x_n$, and $|x-\tilde{x}|<\epsilon$, $f(x) - f(\tilde{x}) = \sum c_n(I(x-x_n) - I(\tilde{x}-x_n))$, we can prove there is a $N(\epsilon)$, such that for all n<N, $I(x-x_n)-I(\tilde{x}-x_n) = 0$.